# How do you use predefined enviornmental varaibles in environmental module files?

Tags: tcl, environment-modules

I'm having trouble using any predefined environmental variable in my module files. For example a line like this `setenv TEST ${HOSTNAME}` throws an error, where `${HOSTNAME}` is defined by the system as a global environmental variable. The error looks like: `ERROR:102: Tcl command execution failed: set TEST ${HOSTNAME}`. I have set environmental variables in the module file itself and tried using those and get the same kind of error. For example,

This **does not** work:

`setenv DUMMY /location/to/some/file
 setenv TEST ${DUMMY}`

I get a similar error as above: `ERROR:102: Tcl command execution failed: set TEST ${DUMMY}`. However,

This works:

`set DUMMY /location/to/some/file
 setenv TEST ${DUMMY}`

There are certain lines that I needed to use predefined global environmental variables, so the above command cannot be used.

How can one use a predefined environmental variable in module files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set` command sets a Tcl variable. These are local to the module processing: they are not exported anywhere else. There are very few restrictions on what characters you can use in a Tcl variable name; about the only ones to *really* beware of are `:` and `(`, though there are a few others that can make things really awkward so it's still best to stick to alphanumerics (and `_`).

The `setenv` command (which is *not* a standard Tcl command, but rather something the `module` system adds) sets environment variables, and these *are* exported to subprocesses. They are also mapped as Tcl variables as elements of the global associative array, `env`, so you can do this

```
setenv DUMMY /location/to/some/file
setenv TEST $env(DUMMY)
```

(The restriction on `(` that I mentioned up above is because this gets tangled up with the syntax for associative arrays. Element names can use *any* character at all. Environment variables probably ought to avoid ASCII NUL and `=` in their names…)

---

The implementation of `setenv` is probably something like this:

```
proc setenv {variable value} {
    global env
    set env($variable) $value
}
```

The mapping to `env` is bi-directional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DonalFellows. This seems to be working well for the `setenv` lines. So this solves that issue. However, I also have a few set-alias lines that are now complaining when using environmental variables in the alias. For example, `set-alias pbin 'cd $env(TEST)'` throws the same error as before. Do you have any insight on using these variables in aliases? Thanks!